# jQuery Deferred/Promises with many getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred, last.fm

I'm trying to learn more about jquery deferred/promises. I sort of understand when you want to do 1 ajax call, but what about doing multiple (x number) ajax calls together? Here is a jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/vRJ7v/

For example (using the lastFM api):

```
var last_fm_url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user='; 
var apiKey = //my lastfm api key;
var user_list = ['user1','user2'.....'userX'];

var getTracks = function( user ){
    var dfd, last_fm_url;

    dfd = $.Deferred();

    last_fm_url = last_fm_url + user + '&limit=10&period=3month&api_key='+ apiKey +'&format=json';

    $.getJSON( last_fm_url ).done(function( results ) {
        dfd.resolve();
    }).fail(function( error ) {
        dfd.reject();
    });

    return dfd.promise();

};

var fetchMultipleTracks = function(){
     var dfd, user_list_count, promises = [];

     var dfd = $.Deferred();

     user_list_count = user_list.length;

     for(var i = 0; i < user_list_count; i++ ){
         promises.push( getTracks(user_list[ i ]) );
     }

     $.when( promises ).done(function(results){
         dfd.resolve();
     });

     return dfd.promise();
};

var test = fetchMultipleTracks();
test.done(function( results ){
  console.log( results );  
}, function( error ){
    // error
});
```

But I can't seem to return the actual results, it just returns http://d.pr/i/N5Yi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.when` accepts one promise per argument, not an array of promises. If you wish to use an array, you must use `.apply` so that you'll apply the array of promises to the `.when` method properly.

```
$.when.apply($,myArrayOfPromises).done(...
```

Additionally, `$.when` returns a promise, so you do not need to generate another one.

```
var fetchMultipleTracks = function(){
     var user_list_count, promises = [];

     user_list_count = user_list.length;

     for(var i = 0; i < user_list_count; i++ ){
         promises.push( getTracks(user_list[ i ]) );
     }

     return $.when.apply($, promises );
};
```

To handle the results, iterate over the arguments array.

```
get_tracks.done(function(){
   $.each(arguments,function(i,result) {
      console.log(result)
      outputTracksToDom(result.toptracks.track);
   });
}).fail(function(error ){
    // handle error
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vRJ7v/1/

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, it only loops through 1 user. Here is a jsfiddle of my complete code. http://jsfiddle.net/vRJ7v/

Comment: right, because `results` is the result from the first request. the second argument will be for the second request, the third will be for the third, and so on. `console.log(arguments)`

Comment: Hmm, how can I output all the tracks from each user I input in the user_list array? If I have 10 users in user_list, then I will need to hard code in 10 arguments? Is there a way that I can combine the results into one big array instead?

Comment: Yes, `arguments` is the array you're looking for. `console.log(arguments)` Note however `arguments` isn't a true array, so it may be missing a few methods that you're familiar with when using arrays.

Comment: Can't seem to figure it out. Any guidance?

Comment: Updated answer to include an example of that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41899/discussion-between-cusejuice-and-kevin-b)